# defining different sets of child nodes by attribute value

Tags: xsd

I'm trying to define a schema for some xml-based database exchange like this:

```
<table name="foo">
 <row>
  <fooid>15</fooid>
  <fooname>some entry</fooname>
 </row>
 <row>
  <fooid>28</fooid>
  <fooname>something else</fooname>
 </row>
</table>
<table name="bar">
 <row>
  <barid>19</barid>
  <barcounter>93</barcounter>
 </row>
</table>
```

so I have several of these tables and within these tables there should be only the fields that exist in these tables. For example barid should not appear in table foo.
Is there any way to define this?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there are two ways. One is simple (and relies on some human intuition and documentation), and the other is more expressive (but inevitably also a bit more complicated.)

The simple way is to replace the names 'table' and 'row' with names that indicate what table we are talking about:

```
<table-foo>
  <row-foo>
    <fooid>28</fooid>
    <fooname>something</fooname>
  </row-foo>
  ...
</table-foo>
<table-bar>
  <row-bar>
    <barid>19</barid>
    <barcounter>93</barcounter>
  </row-bar>
  ...
</table-bar>
```

XSD validation (like validation using DTDs and Relax NG) is based principally on the element names used.  If you want two different kinds of row to contain different things, give them two different names.  So foo-table and its descendants can be declared thus:

```
<xs:element name="table-foo" substitutionGroup="tns:table">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>            
      <xs:element ref="tns:row-foo"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

<xs:element name="row-foo" substitutionGroup="tns:row">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>            
      <xs:element ref="tns:fooid"/>          
      <xs:element ref="tns:fooname"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
```

And similarly for bar-table and bar-row.

Sometimes, however, we absolutely must, or really want to, capture the fact that both 'row-foo' and 'row-bar' have something crucial in common.  They are both 'rows' in some abstract ontology, and that may matter to us.  In such cases, you can use abstract elements to capture the regularity.

For example, here is a simple abstraction for tables, rows, and cells:

```
<xs:element name="table" 
            abstract="true" 
            type="tns:table"/>
<xs:element name="row" 
            abstract="true" 
            type="tns:row"/>
<xs:element name="cell" 
            abstract="true" 
            type="xs:anySimpleType"/>
```

The types for table and row are straightforward:

```
<xs:complexType name="table">
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element ref="tns:row" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="row">
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element ref="tns:cell" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

Now, the declarations for table-foo etc. become slightly more complicated, because for each declaration we have to establish a relation to the abstraction we have just defined.  Element foo-table is an instantiation of the table abstraction, and its type is a restriction of the abstract table type:

```
<xs:element name="table-foo" 
            substitutionGroup="tns:table">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexContent>
      <xs:restriction base="tns:table">
        <xs:sequence>            
          <xs:element ref="tns:row-foo"/>
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:restriction>
    </xs:complexContent>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Element foo-row is similar:  we specify that it's a "row" by using the substitutionGroup attribute, and we derive its complex type by restriction from the abstract row type:

```
<xs:element name="row-foo" substitutionGroup="tns:row">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexContent>
      <xs:restriction base="tns:row">
        <xs:sequence>            
          <xs:element ref="tns:fooid"/>          
          <xs:element ref="tns:fooname"/>
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:restriction>
    </xs:complexContent>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Note that we don't allow arbitrary cells to appear here, just the two cell types we want for rows from table foo.  And to close off the pattern, we declare that the elements fooid and fooname are cells, using (again) substitutionGroup.

```
<xs:element name="fooid" type="xs:integer" 
            substitutionGroup="tns:cell"/>
<xs:element name="fooname" type="xs:string" 
            substitutionGroup="tns:cell"/>
```

The same patterns can be used to declare a different set of legal cells for table bar:

```
<xs:element name="barid" type="xs:positiveInteger" 
            substitutionGroup="tns:cell"/>
<xs:element name="barcounter" type="xs:double" 
            substitutionGroup="tns:cell"/>

<xs:element name="table-bar" substitutionGroup="tns:table">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexContent>
      <xs:restriction base="tns:table">
        <xs:sequence>            
          <xs:element ref="tns:row-bar"/>
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:restriction>
    </xs:complexContent>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

<xs:element name="row-bar" substitutionGroup="tns:row"> 
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexContent>
      <xs:restriction base="tns:row">
        <xs:sequence>            
          <xs:element ref="tns:barid"/>          
          <xs:element ref="tns:barcounter"/>
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:restriction>
    </xs:complexContent>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

The situation you describe is one of the use cases for which abstract elements and substitution groups were designed. Other techniques which could also be used here (but which I won't illustrate in detail) include:

- Declared subtypes, use of xsi:type (declare foo-table and bar-table as restrictions or extensions of type table, use `<table xsi:type="tns:foo-table">...</table>` or `<table xsi:type="tns:bar-table">...</table>` to guide validation)
- Assertions (declare foo-table and bar-table types which extend the generic table type by adding assertions about the grandchildren -- this is an XSD 1.1 feature not available in 1.0).
- Conditional type assignment (declare that `table` gets one type if it has `name="foo"` and a different type if it has `name="bar"` -- also an XSD 1.1 feature not available in 1.0).

There may be other ways to do it, too.